# How to convert Excel file in csv and read data from iphone

Tags: ios, excel, csv

I want to make an application that read excel file from url and convert data in to csv file and then i can read the csv file and display the data. how can i do this. please help me.

Comment: Why do you need to convert to CSV just to read the Excel file?

Comment: @  rmaddy but how to read Excel file. i google it but not find any solution. please help me.

Comment: Did you see the answer by erhnby below?

Comment: @ rmaddy i see but only provide class for that. how to code and how to fetch xml file not provide step by step.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .xls file, you can use the open source DHlibxls library to read the file into your app. This is an ObjectiveC framework that wraps a C-based library. The library is quite mature.

Answer (score 0):

How to convert Excel file in csv
[Click here](https://www.completecampaigns.com/WebHelp/Management/Imports/How_to_convert_an_existing_Excel_file_into_a_csv_format.htm)

and read data from iphone

//****************** Get Data fron CSV file  **********************//

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NameYourCsvFile" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSError* error;
    dataStr=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&error ];
```

Comment: but i want to convert file programatically in from xls to csv.